# Invoice Generator using checkboxes - Undefined Offset [2] PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to generate multiple invoices in a school management system.
Here is the issue:

For example I have 10 students in the DB

I am able to generate the invoices if the students are selected in consecutive order. 
Student 1, Student 2, Student 3, Student 4

But once I miss a student from the consecutive order and try to generate in a random order it gives me an undefined offset error:
Student 1, Student 4, Student 5, Student 7

Here is the code:

```
    for($x = 1; $x <= count($this->input->post('studentId')); $x++) {                               
        $insert_data = array(                                   
            'class_id'      => $this->input->post('className'),
            'section_id'    => $this->input->post('sectionName'),
            'student_id'    => $this->input->post('studentId')[$x],         
            'payment_name_id' => $payment_name_id
        );

        $status = $this->db->insert('payment', $insert_data);
    }

    return ($status === true ? true : false);
```

The same also applies to editing the invoices once it has been generated. 
I even tried changing the for loop to a while loop for that one, which does not give me any error but it just doesn't save if the students selected are in a random order:

```
            $x = 1;
            $form_fields = count($this->input->post('editStudentId')); 

            while($x <= $form_fields) { 

                    if(!empty($this->input->post('editStudentId')[$x])) {
                        $update_payment_data = array(                                   
                            'class_id'      => $this->input->post('editClassName'),
                            'section_id'    => $this->input->post('editSectionName'),
                            'student_id'    => $this->input->post('editStudentId')[$x],         
                            'payment_name_id' => $id
                        );

                        $status = $this->db->insert('payment', $update_payment_data);
                    }

                $x++;
            }

            return ($status === true ? true : false);
```

IMAGE - SELECTING STUDENTS:
[image: Selecting Students]

IMAGE- POST SAVE WITH JUST 2 out of the 4 I SELECTED:
[image: Post Save]

Comment: you have to apply `foreach` loop instead of `while` or `for` loop. It will take care of indexes

Comment: They were both for loops, but I changed the for to a while loop to see if it would work. The While loop doesn't produce errors like the for but it just doesn't save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `for` with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($this->input->post('studentId') as $studentId) {
    $insert_data = array(                                   
        'class_id'      => $this->input->post('className'),
        'section_id'    => $this->input->post('sectionName'),
        'student_id'    => $studentId,         
        'payment_name_id' => $payment_name_id
    );

    $status = $this->db->insert('payment', $insert_data);
}
```

Comment: he is asking for second code , which is not working.BTW approach is correct

Comment: Maybe because it uses `editStudentId` and not `studentId`?

Comment: lool, coincidently the foreach loop worked on creating the invoices! Trying it on the edit and will mark as correct if it also works

Comment: Hey man your a life saver, all working as expected! lool, was that simple!